# Transaction for sql query stored in temp table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure build update query and store in temp table each time in loop.

Total query built UNKNOWN (2 to 4)

How can I put multi query in a transaction?

For example, temp table contains following rows in column `EXPSQL` (`nvarchar`)

```
id   EXPSQL
1    Update tableA SET Name = 'Test' WHERE id=1
2    Update tableB SET Name = 'Test2' WHERE id=10
```

How can I begin a transaction for a loop to exec above query? or is there any other way?

```
while @id < total
begin
    set @id = @id +1
    select @SQL = EXPSQL FROM #TEMPTABLE WHERE id=@id
    EXEC (@SQL)
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute all as one:

```
begin transaction

while @id < total
begin
    set @id = @id +1
    select @SQL = EXPSQL FROM #TEMPTABLE WHERE id=@id
    EXEC (@SQL)

    -- if a error occurs go back to the original state
    if(@@error <> 0)
       rollback transaction
end

commit transaction
```

---

If you want to execute each one individually:

```
while @id < total
begin
    set @id = @id +1
    select @SQL = EXPSQL FROM #TEMPTABLE WHERE id=@id

    begin transaction
    EXEC (@SQL)

    -- if a error occurs go back to the original state
    if(@@error <> 0)
       rollback transaction
    else
       commit transaction
end
```